# How to extract $lastexitcode from c# powershell script execution

Tags: c#, powershell, scripting, exit-code, pshost

I've got a scipt executing in C# using the powershell async execution code on code project here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/AsyncPowerShell.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=407636&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2130851#xx2130851xx

I need to return the $lastexitcode and Jean-Paul describes how you can use a custom pshost class to return it. I can't find any method or property in pshost that returns the exit code.

This engine I have needs to ensure that script executes correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

regards
Bob.

Its the $lastexitcode and the $? variables I need to bring back.

Hi,
Finally answered.
I found out about the $host variable. It implements a callback into the host, specifically a custom PSHost object, enabling you to return the $lastexitcode. Here is a link to an explanation of $host.

http://mshforfun.blogspot.com/2006/08/do-you-know-there-is-host-variable.html

It seems to be obscure, badly documented, as usual with powershell docs. Using point 4, calling $host.SetShouldExit(1) returns 1 to the SetShouldExit method of pshost, as described here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshost.setshouldexit(VS.85).aspx

Its really depends on defining your own exit code defintion. 0 and 1 suffixes I guess.

regards
Bob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function you can try:

```
function run-process ($cmd, $params) {
$p = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$exitcode = $false  
$p.StartInfo.FileName = $cmd
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = $params
$p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $shell
$p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = 1; #hidden.  Comment out this line to show output in separate console
$null = $p.Start()
$p.WaitForExit()
$exitcode = $p.ExitCode
$p.Dispose()    
return $exitcode
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can write in your script code that will check the $lastexitcode and will [throw an exception](http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/) if the exitcode is not what you excepted.
Exceptions are easier to catch.

Comment: Aw right ok. I've had a look at Trap. I'll check it out. I'm assume it returns in to the c# runtime, returned through the errors collection.

Comment: Hi Shay, is possible say throw an exception if the $? code is false.

Comment: you mean something like: if ($lastexitcode -eq 0) throw (new-object system.Exception("Error")

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are making a mountain out of a molehill by using this code project.  Asynchronous execution is very easy to do in C#.

```
PowerShell psCmd = PowerShell.Create().AddScript({Invoke-YourScriptAndReturnLastExitCode});
IAsyncResult result = psCmd.BeginInvoke();
// wait for finish
psCmd.EndInvoke(result);
```

Also, looking at your question on that project, it looks like you are trying to use TFS in PowerShell.  You can consider the following additional pieces of information:

1. [TFS has cmdlets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx)
2. Many other people have worked TFS cmdlets, i.e. [PSTFS](http://pstfs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get-TFS-EN)
3. You can always copy the tfs executable wherever you need it, which sidesteps at least part of your scripts pain.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi MediaAndMicrocode, I never used lances code. I used a similar method to the one above, except much more robust, where I used a producer/consumer queue where each queue entry is a pshell execution block with the queue being services by several threads. A thread dequeues a execution block and selects 1 of several pshell execution engines, depending if they were blocked or not by an Autoresetevent. It works fine, is performant and is exactly what I was looking for. 

Thanks for the help.
Bob.

Comment: I would use the TPL and the above now.