# How to catch exit code from a powershell script in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, powershell

I have a powershell script which is run by c#. Below is my code:

```cs
string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\power.ps1");
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(data);
    IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke();
    while (!result.IsCompleted)
    {
        Logger.Info("Wait initiated");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

How can I read the exit code after completing the script?

Comment: I don't see any exit code in your code. There is not even an "exit"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here [Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/kebab/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c)

```
// begin invoke execution on the pipeline
// use this overload to specify an output stream buffer
IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

...

foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
{
    //TODO: handle/process the output items if required
    Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
}
```

Comment: what is outputCollection?

Comment: PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question but maybe the question itself is wrong. The exit code is stored in $LASTEXITCODE but this doesn't seem to be too easy to use in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/780047/2523899